# Problems with common dialog functions in a binary dll

Tags: c++, dll, dialog, vb6

I did a simple test of using common dialog in a console application and everything worked properly. Then I tried to use the same code putting it in a binary dll. I called my function from Vb 6 and strange things have begun to happen.

I have already tried to call other functions from vb 6 contained in this dll without problems.

With the common dialog, on the first call, the dialog appears correctly. The next calls vb says it cannot find the dll (error 53) and I have to close and reopen the IDE of vb 6. It only happens using the common dialog functions. For every other type of code this problem does not occur.

Here is the code:

C++:

```
bool _stdcall FsDialog(HWND hwnd){
    OPENFILENAME openFile;
    wchar_t szFileName[MAX_PATH];
    wchar_t szFileTitle[MAX_PATH];
    int index = 0;

    ZeroMemory( &openFile, sizeof(OPENFILENAME) );
    openFile.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);

    szFileTitle[0] = '\0';
    szFileName[0] = '\0';
    openFile.hwndOwner = hwnd;
    openFile.lpstrFilter = L"Logs (*.log)\0*.log\0";
    openFile.lpstrFile = szFileName;
    openFile.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
    openFile.lpstrFileTitle = szFileTitle;
    openFile.nMaxFileTitle = sizeof(szFileTitle)/sizeof(*szFileTitle);
    openFile.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY;
    openFile.lpstrDefExt = L"log";

    if (GetOpenFileName(&openFile)){
        return(1);
    }
}
```

VB6:

```
Private Declare Function FsDialog Lib "mydll.dll" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Integer

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Debug.Print FsDialog(Me.hWnd)
End Sub
```

Comment: To clarify, are you saying that the first call to 'FsDialog' works OK, but any later calls produce error 53?

Comment: what You return if You are clicking "Cancel" ?

Comment: @DaveInCaz not exactly. In the test it was initial under the click of a button

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Debug.Print FsDialog(Me.hWnd)
End Sub

Clicking the dialog appears correctly. Whether you choose a file and click to open or click on cancel, the dialog works correctly. I can click 100 times on the button. Now, if I close the form and reopen it, when I click on the button the error 53 appears. It's as if, in the closing of the form, something does not get rid of the memory correctly but I have no idea what it is, it never happened to me other times

Comment: @deblocker it return always 1, it's just a test with the minimum code to try to understand the problem